# Run script with virtualenv on init

Tags: script, init

I have  bash script which loads a virtualenv and run 3 python scripts.

I have tried to init on startup by ini.d and rc.local methods but it doesnt work and I have no idea why is not working but if I start it manually it works

the content of run.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.profile
workon cv
python socket1.py & python socket2.py & python socket3.py
```

Comment: init.d and rc.local are not aware of your user id, it uses root, so ~/.profile is not where you think it is. Try using the full path. BTW: why do you start the first script with 'python' and the other 2 using the scripts' executable attributes/ shebang settings (check what the ampersand does on the command line)

Answer (score 3):

I have solved it by using

```
source /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/activate
```

instead of

```
source ~/.profile & workon cv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **systemd** Unit file to start your script. With it you are able to exactly set the environment to that one used on the command line. The only difficulty is to find the environment needed for your programs. I suggest to start with this Unit file:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --full --force edit myrun.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them an quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=My run script
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/scripts
Environment="ENV_VAR=important variable"
ExecStart=/path/to/run.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You may have a look at `man systemd.exec` to see what's possible with environment. It is also important, what output your scripts have, if it is text only or graphical. We will see. Enable the service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable myrun.service
```

and reboot.

Here some commands for troubleshooting:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --full edit myrun.service   # edit again
rpi ~$ systemctl status myrun.service             # get status of the service
rpi ~$ journalctl -b -e                 # looking at the journal for all logs
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i have solved it by using  "source /home/pi/.virtualenvs/myVirtualEnv/bin/activate" instead of  "source ~/.profile & workon cv"

Comment: @Jandako Please make an answer with the final solution so other users can benefit of it. It will also finish the question.